# why are multiple DBs actually needed?

Tags: database, database-design

I was looking at godaddy.com which says they offer up to 10 MySQL DBs, but I don't know why you would need more than 1 ever since a DB can have mutliple tables. Can't multiple DBs be integrated into a single DB? Is there an example case where its better or unfeasible to not have multiple ones? And how do you differentiate between them when you want to call them, from their directory or from a name?

Best,

Comment: In addition to Jonathan's comments remember the old saying "don't put all of your eggs in one basket". Just because you *can* store every single application in seperate tables in a single database doesn't mean that it's a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess separation of concerns would be the most obvious answer. In the same way you can have all of your functionality in one humongous class in object oriented programming, it's a good idea to keep non-related information separate. It's easier to wrap your head around smaller chunks of data, and future developers mights start to think tables are related, and aggregate data in a way they were never meant to.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you're doing two different projects with two different teams. Maybe you won't one team to access the other team tables.

There can also be a space limit in each database, and It each one can be configured with specific params to optimize the performance.

In other hand, two final users can be assigned to make the backups of each entire database, and you wan`t one user to make the backup of the other DB because he could be able to restore the database in other place and access the first database data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are some pretty good DBAs on the forum who can answer this in detail.

Storing tables in different databases makes because you are able to backup them up individually. Furthermore, you will be able to control access to each database under different NT groups (e.g. Admin vs. users). Although this can be done at the indvidual table level, sometimes it makes sense to grant or deny access to an entire database to a particular group.

When you need to call them in SQL Server you need to append the database name to the query like this `SELECT * FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable]`.

Answer (score 0):

One other reason to use separate databases relates to whether you need full transactional recovery or not. For instance, if I havea bunch of tables that are populated on a schedule through import processes and never by the users, putting them in a separate database allows me to set the recovery mode to simple which reduces the logging (a good thing when you are loading millions of records at once). I can also not do transactional log backup every fifteen minutes like I do for the data in the database with the user inserted data. It could also make recovery a faster process when needed as the databases would be smaller and thus individally take less time to recover. Won't help much when the whole server crashes but it could help a lot if onely one datbase gets corrupted for some reason. If the data relates to different applications, it simplifies the security as well to have the data in separte databases. And of course sometimes we have commercial databases and we can;t add tables to those and so may need a separate database to handles some things we want to add to that data (we do this for instance with our Project Management software, we have a spearate database where we extract and summarize data from the PM system for reporting and then write all our custome reports off that.)